# Only 2T for using after I fdisk the disk

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a 4T disk:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486401 cylinders, total 7814037168 sectors
Units = section of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

After I use fdisk for partitioned to 2 parts. but I only get 2T for using.

I only get 2T for using:

```
/dev/sdc1       939G   72M  891G    1% /media/summer/sdc1
/dev/sdc2       1.1T   71M 1023G    1% /media/summer/sdc2
```

I am using CentOS 7.2 system.

---

**EDIT-01**

When I take partition:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486401 cylinders, total 7814037168 sectors
Units = sector of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   device launch      start          end     blocks  Id  system

command(type m for help)： n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
part number (1-4，defualt 1)： 
will use default 1
start sector (2048-4294967295，default 2048)： 
will use default 2048
Last sector, +sector or +size{K,M,G} (2048-4294967294，default 4294967294)：
```

You see the `total sectors` are `7814037168`, but when I take partition, the choice is `2048-4294967294`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old MBR partition table, which can't handle disks larger than 2TB. You have to create a [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) to use the whole disk.

Additionally, older fdisk versions can't handle GPT, so you need a different fdisk tool.

Partitioning tools that support GPT:

- cfdisk
- parted
- fdisk with version v2.23 and newer
- gdisk

cfdisk is often already installed.

Comment: I can not install the `cfdisk ` in Ubuntu.  `apt-get install cfdisk` says there is no this package.

Comment: why did you tag your question with `centos` when you are using ubuntu?

Comment: cfdisk is in the `util-linux` package on ubuntu. It should be installed by default.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: `fdisk` under CentOS 7 has "experimental" support for GPT (this is `util-linux 2012 June 2012`.) In Ubuntu 16.04 (with `util-linux` from Sept. 2013), the "experimental" remark is gone from the man page.